# Laravel Model Can not Find Factory

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I create model to another path

```
namespace Core\Entity;

use Core\Base\BaseEntity;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class News extends BaseEntity 
{
    use HasFactory;
```

And This is My seeder

```
use Core\Entity\News;

class NewsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
           News::factory(500)->create();
    }
```

And This is my factory

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\Core\Entity\News>
 */
class NewsFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

Problem Is it Can not Find path of Factory , gives me like this ERROR

```
  Class "Database\Factories\Core\Entity\NewsFactory" not found
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Try after running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I did , but not helped

Comment: DId you upgrade the laravel version ? Also, what is your laravel version?

Comment: Also your model seems at a different namespace isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Update your namespace in Factory class:

```
namespace Database\Factories;
```

to

```
namespace Database\Factories\Core\Entity;
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I think , it is not correct way.

Comment: But did work? Maybe related to `@extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\Core\Entity\News>`